# Normalize data with Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

All

I am just unable to get around my head with the issue, so posting is here for some help.

I have a object that contains the following

- Product Id
- CustomFieldName
- CustomFieldValue

and for the same product Id there are multiple enteries.Example:

ProductId-----CustomFieldName---CustomFieldValue

111111111-----firstName---------TestUser

111111111-----lastName----------TestFUser

111111111-----phoneNumber-------1243

222111111-----firstName---------AnotherTestUser

222111111-----phoneNumber-------5243

I want to normalize the data, in another object:

ProductId-----firstName---------lastName------phoneNumber

111111111-----TestUser----------TestFUser-----1243

222111111-----AnotherTestUser---NULL----------5243

I tried normalizing it with Maps in for loop, but the code did not work for me. I cannot paste the code but here is the high level

```
Define a Map
//mapAttributes has the non-normalized data

Map<Id, Map<String, String>> mapme = new Map<Id, Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> tryme; 
for (String a: mapAttributes.keySet())
{
    tryme = new Map<String, String>();   
    tryme.put(mapAttributes.get(a).CustomFieldName, mapAttributes.get(a).CustomFieldValue);
    mapme.put(mapAttributes.get(a).Id, tryme);
}
```

The outcome of the code is that the "tryme" looks like a reference and all the products have the same first,lastname and phone number...

I am not sure how can I normalize the data. The solution was so easy in my head, but in practicality is not working.

Any other approach of solving is appreciated as well.

I want to solve it in Salesforce Apex, can someone please help

Comment: What is the key in your `mapAttributes`? I mean it can't be productid because it wouldn't be unique. Or do you have a plain list of strings maybe?

Comment: I am sorry, I should have added the input as it is a JSON repr of the table structure I pasted. Something like 
{
ProductId: "123332",
CustomFieldName: "firstName",
CustomFieldValue: "TestUser"
}

Comment: Cool, glad I could help! You know you can feed your source data to https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/, it'll generate matching Apex wrapper class. Easier parsing and processing it. If you wish post your own answer, I'd gladly upvote it ;)

Comment: Wow, that is brilliant...  I never knew such thing existed... Thank you again for sharing very helpful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends how your source data structure looks like.

```apex
List<String> lines = new List<String>{
    '111111111-----firstName---------TestUser',
    '111111111-----lastName----------TestFUser',
    '111111111-----phoneNumber-------1243',
    '222111111-----firstName---------AnotherTestUser',
    '222111111-----phoneNumber-------5243'
};
    
Map<String, Map<String, String>> collated = new Map<String, Map<String, String>>();
for(String l : lines){
    List<String> columns = l.split('\\-+'); // split by "-", treat multiple as one
    String key = columns[0];
    if(collated.containsKey(key)){
        collated.get(key).put(columns[1], columns[2]);
    } else {
        collated.put(key, new Map<String, String>{columns[1] => columns[2]});
    }
}

System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(collated));
```

gives

```
{
  "222111111" : {
    "phoneNumber" : "5243",
    "firstName" : "AnotherTestUser"
  },
  "111111111" : {
    "phoneNumber" : "1243",
    "lastName" : "TestFUser",
    "firstName" : "TestUser"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) After looking at your code I realised one of the biggest mistake I made was to treat MapAttributes key as the primary key :(. But now I changed it again, thank you for your code and you taking extra step to splitting --, it was my bad that I did not share the input :( but your code was spot on :) Thanks again.